# Remove fonts from Zebra printer

Tags: printing, fonts, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I am trying to remove some fonts from the Zebra ZT410 memory which I loaded them during testing. I deleted them using the Zebra Designer Fonts but when I print the command `^XA^WD*:*.TTF*^XZ` to show me the fonts stored on the printer it still shows me those fonts that I deleted in the E: directory of the printer. Can somebody please help me to delete them from the printer.

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ZPL manual:

```
^ID – Object Delete
```

The ^ID command deletes objects, graphics, fonts, and stored formats from storage areas. Objects can be deleted selectively or in groups. This command can be used within a printing format to delete objects before saving new ones, or in a stand-alone format to delete objects.

The image name and extension support the use of the asterisk (*) as a wild card. This allows you to easily delete a selected groups of objects.

Format: ^IDd:o.x
Parameters Details

d = location of stored object
Values: R:, E:, B:, and A:
Default: R:

o = object name
Values: any 1 to 8 character name
Default: if a name is not specified, UNKNOWN is used

x = extension Values: any extension conforming to Zebra conventions
Default: .GRF

Example 1: To delete stored formats from DRAM:
^XA
^IDR:*.ZPL^FS
^XZ

Example 2: To delete formats and images named SAMPLE from DRAM, regardless of the
extension:
^XA
^IDR:SAMPLE.*^FS
^XZ

Example 3: To delete the image SAMPLE1.GRF prior to storing SAMPLE2.GRF:
^XA
^FO25,25^AD,18,10
^FDDelete^FS
^FO25,45^AD,18,10
^FDthen Save^FS
^IDR:SAMPLE1.GRF^FS
^ISR:SAMPLE2.GRF^FS^XZ

Example 4: In this the * is a wild card, indicating that all objects with the .GRF extension are deleted:
^XA
^IDR:*.GRF^FS
^XZ